# Validar caracteres en nombre de usuario mediante una expresión regular en javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy tratando de validar el nombre de usuario y clave ingresados. Para la clave, busco que se haya ingresado cualquier valor. Para el nombre de usuario, quiero utilizar la siguiente expresión regular:

```
/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i
```

Quiero **que no permita el login en caso de no coincidir con la expresión regular**, pero no sé si se pueda hacer con la misma condición del código.

Intenté con `.test()` pero no sé por qué no me funciona.

El código que intenté:

```
function loginUsuario() {

    var usuario = document.getElementById("form-login-username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("form-login-password").value.replace('+', '%2b');
    var validausuario = /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i;

    if ((usuario == '') || (password == '') || (usuario == validausuario.test(document.getElementById('fomr-login-username').value)))
    {

        document.getElementById('formaLoginError').hidden = false;
        document.getElementById('formaLogin').hidden = true;

        document.getElementById('lblError').innerHTML = '<strong>Error!</strong> Favor de ingresar usuario y contraseña correctamente.'
    }
}
```

Comment: No se si ahora si esta bien corregida la pregunta?

Comment: modifiqué un poco la pregunta para que se entienda mejor. Si hay algo que no esté bien, por favor avisame o modificalo directamente.

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que hace la expresión regular?

Comment: Da el formato de un correo electrónico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por supuesto que se puede usar ese regex para validar el nombre de usuario. Veo que estás usando un patrón que coincide si se ingresó un texto similar a una dirección de mail.

El tema principal es cómo estás planteando la condición en el `if`. Si la condición del `if` es **verdadera**, los valores ingresados son **incorrectos**. Por lo tanto, buscaríamos algo como:

```
if ((password está vacía) || (usuario NO COINCIDE con el regex)) {
    //Mostrar el error
}
```

- Nótese que no hace falta verificar que `usuario` no esté vacío, porque eso ya lo verifica el regex.

Esto mismo, con las variables que usaste en tu código:

```
if ((password == '') || !validausuario.test(usuario))
```

- El signo **`!`** precediendo a `.test()` niega a la condición (si es verdadero, se convierte  en falso y viceversa)

---

Por lo tanto, el código quedaría:

```js
function loginUsuario() {

    var usuario = document.getElementById("form-login-username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("form-login-password").value.replace('+', '%2b');
    var validausuario = /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i;

    if ((password == '') || !validausuario.test(usuario)) {

        document.getElementById('formaLoginError').hidden = false;
        document.getElementById('formaLogin').hidden = true;

        document.getElementById('lblError').innerHTML = '<strong>Error!</strong> Favor de ingresar usuario y contraseña correctamente.';
    } else {
        console.log('VALORES CORRECTOS: Usuario validado y clave no vacía');
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="formaLogin">
    Usuario:
    <input type="text" id="form-login-username">
    Password:
    <input type="text" id="form-login-password">
    <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="loginUsuario();">
</form>

<span id="formaLoginError" hidden>formaLoginError<br /></span>
<span id="lblError"></span>
```

---

**Nota:** Personalmente, no me gusta mucho cómo está armada esa expresión regular. Yo, en cambio, usaría la siguiente:

```
/^[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(?:\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*@(?:[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@"]{2,63}$/i
```